# socket.io only emits on page refesh

Tags: python, angularjs, flask, socket.io

I have set up a simple web app using Flash/AngularJS and socket.io.  I have an "admin" page that is password protected and has a MySQL backend that populates the settings page when authentication is successful.  I've run in to an issue where when I first load the page, nothing is prepopulated until I refresh the browser page.

From my app.py:

```
@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
"""
Called when we successfully navigate to the administrative settings page
:return: Flask.render_template, corresponding either to login.html or admin.html (depending on if credentials
were valid)
"""

global default_settings

my_logger.info('============= PAGE LOADED: settings')

# Refreshes default settings to make sure it is up to date with DB
default_settings = db_get_saved()

# If we have been logged out by the scan page, forces user to re-enter credentials
if not session.get('logged_in') and default_settings['user_pw'] != '':
    return render('login.html', request.path)


    # Otherwise renders the admin.html page
else:
    return render('admin.html', request.path)


def render(template, path):
"""
Called by our Flask app when a new page is loaded. Renders corresponding HTML document
:param template: string, name of the HTML document to be rendered
:param path: string, path of this document
:param logo_menu: company logo to be displayed on front page in the menu bar
:param logo_footer: company logo to be displayed on front page in footer
:return: Flask.render_template, corresponds to the passed in parameters
"""

my_logger.info('Rendering page: ' + template)

logo = ''

if default_settings["company_logo"] != '':
    logo = '/static/uploads/' + default_settings["company_logo"]

return render_template(template, app_name='My App', menu=create_menu(path), user_js='admin',
                       logo=logo)
```

Once the page renders, the form should be populated using a function in app.py called fe_get_settings, which is called from angular_controller.js:

```
// ----------------------- Socket Event Handlers

socket.on('connect', function() {
    /*
    Listens for initial connect message from the socketio server. When connection occurs, requests default settings
    from the DB
     */

    socket.emit('fe_get_settings');

});
```

Again, everything works, but only after I load the admin page and then refresh it.  Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Trying using `socket.send('fe_get_settings')` instead of emit, emit is usually used to send object ex `socket.emit('data', {key: "value"});` and it sends it to all connected clients

Comment: Also the event `on('connect')` will only happen when a client connects to the server which is why it's only updating on page refresh. You're probably looking for another type of event, maybe `socket.onmessage()`

Comment: Perfect, thanks -- I tried the send, but it exhibited the same behaviour, so I'll look into socket.onmessage(), would I have to change much code?  This might be a stupid question, but why doesn't the client also connect on load?

Comment: No not not much this is how it would start `socket.onmessage = function(e) {}` then `console.log(e)` and try to update your stuff off of that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again!

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Comment: I'm attempting an implementation right now, just trying to wrap my head around the syntax change.

Comment: socket.onmessage seems to be a websocket thing, not socket.io....am I wrong on that?

Comment: It could be if you could post your flask handler so we can see